# date and time are not getting updated using setInterval in hooks

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to update the date and time for each and every minute. I have used setinterval for that, but i cant able to update the time using react hooks.

```
const Link = (props) => {
let date = new Date();
const [dateTime, setDateTime] = useState({ curTime: date.toLocaleDateString(),
    timeStr: date.toLocaleTimeString().replace(/:\d{2}\s/, " "),
    curDay: date.toLocaleDateString("en-US", { weekday: "short" })  
});    
setInterval(() => {
    setDateTime({
        curTime: date.toLocaleDateString(),
        timeStr: date.toLocaleTimeString().replace(/:\d{2}\s/, " "),
        curDay: date.toLocaleDateString("en-US", { weekday: "short" })
      });
      console.log(dateTime);
    },
    60000
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must remember a few things

**First:** The parameters passed to the `useState` function are used only once whenthe component mounts

**Second:** `setInterval` must not be called directly but within `useEffect`.

**Third:** You must take care of closures

**Fourth:** State update with the same value over and over again will not cause re-renders and hence use the date from the initial closure in setInterval always

**Fifth:** You must clear the interval when the component is unmounted.

```js
    const Link = (props) => {
    
        let date = new Date();
        const [dateTime, setDateTime] = React.useState({ curTime: date.toLocaleDateString(),
            timeStr: date.toLocaleTimeString().replace(/:\d{2}\s/, " "),
            curDay: date.toLocaleDateString("en-US", { weekday: "short" })  
        });  
    
        React.useEffect(() => {  
        
            const interval = setInterval(() => {
                const date = new Date();
                setDateTime({
                    curTime: date.toLocaleDateString(),
                    timeStr: date.toLocaleTimeString().replace(/:\d{2}\s/, " "),
                    curDay: date.toLocaleDateString("en-US", { weekday: "short" })
                });
                console.log(dateTime);
                },
                60000
              );
            return () => { clearInterval(interval)}
        }, [])
        const {curTime, timeStr, curDay} = dateTime;
        return (
           <div>
            <div>CurTime: {curTime}</div>
            <div>TimeStr: {timeStr}</div>
            <div>CurDay: {curDay}</div>
           </div>
        )
    }
    
ReactDOM.render(<Link />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"/>
```

Comment: i tried with this one, but the value is not getting update.

Comment: @John_ny Updated my answer with a demo, there were a few typos earlier